# Collecting Logs in full depth

Tags: centos, logs

We have a Linux server, whose logs are collected by EventLog Analyzer on a Windows machine. I need to collect logs of events in full detail format, e.g

```
/home/aa/bb/a.xlsx
/home/xxx/sss/b.doc
```

Instead I get e.g

```
/home/aa/bb/
/home/xxx/sss/
```

I have attached a screenshot of my `rsyslog.conf` file

### [image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots! Instead [edit] your question to paste the content of your config file.